Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'Vue') at initBackend, how can i solve this error?
I’m working on a Vue 3 application using Pinia for state management, and I’m encountering an issue where added messages are not rendering on the screen. Additionally, I’m getting a persistent error in the console from Vue Devtools.
I’ve set up my Vue 3 application with Pinia, and I’m trying to build a simple Todo List application. The structure includes three main components: App.vue, ParentComponent.vue, and ChildComponent.vue.
**App.vue
**
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <h1>Vue 3 Pinia Example with Persistent Todo List</h1>
    <ParentComponent />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { onMounted } from 'vue'
import { useTodoStore } from './stores/todo'
import ParentComponent from './components/ParentComponent.vue'

export default {
  name: 'App',
  components: {
    ParentComponent
  },
  setup() {
    const todoStore = useTodoStore()
    onMounted(() => {
      todoStore.loadMessages()
    })
  }
}
</script>

**ParentComponent.vue
**
<template>
  <div>
    <h2>Parent Component</h2>
    <input v-model="newMessage" placeholder="Enter new message" />
    <button @click="addMessage">Add Message</button>
    <ChildComponent />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { ref } from 'vue'
import { useTodoStore } from '../stores/todo'
import ChildComponent from './ChildComponent.vue'

export default {
  name: 'ParentComponent',
  components: {
    ChildComponent
  },
  setup() {
    const todoStore = useTodoStore()
    const newMessage = ref('')

    const addMessage = () => {
      if (newMessage.value.trim() !== '') {
        todoStore.addMessage(newMessage.value)
        newMessage.value = ''
      }
    }

    return {
      newMessage,
      addMessage
    }
  }
}
</script>

**ChildComponent.vue
**
<template>
  <div>
    <h3>Child Component</h3>
    <ul>
      <li v-for="(message, index) in messages" :key="index">
        <input v-model="messages[index]" />
        <button @click="updateMessage(index, messages[index])">Update</button>
        <button @click="deleteMessage(index)">Delete</button>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { useTodoStore } from '../stores/todo'

export default {
  name: 'ChildComponent',
  setup() {
    const todoStore = useTodoStore()

    return {
      messages: todoStore.messages,
      updateMessage: todoStore.updateMessage,
      deleteMessage: todoStore.deleteMessage
    }
  }
}
</script>

**pinia store (/src/stores/todo.js)
**
import { defineStore } from 'pinia'
import { ref } from 'vue'

export const useTodoStore = defineStore('todo', () => {
  const messages = ref([])

  const loadMessages = () => {
    const savedMessages = localStorage.getItem('messages')
    if (savedMessages) {
      messages.value = JSON.parse(savedMessages)
    }
  }

  const saveMessages = () => {
    localStorage.setItem('messages', JSON.stringify(messages.value))
  }

  const addMessage = (newMessage) => {
    messages.value.push(newMessage)
    saveMessages()
  }

  const updateMessage = (index, newMessage) => {
    messages.value[index] = newMessage
    saveMessages()
  }

  const deleteMessage = (index) => {
    messages.value.splice(index, 1)
    saveMessages()
  }

  return {
    messages,
    loadMessages,
    addMessage,
    updateMessage,
    deleteMessage
  }
})

Issues
1.Messages Not Rendering: When I add messages, they don’t render on the screen. However, the messages are correctly stored in the localStorage and are reflected in the Pinia store state.
2.Vue Devtools Error: I keep getting the following error in the console, which might be related:
backend.js:2119 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'Vue') at initBackend (backend.js:2119:28)
•   Confirmed that messages are being stored and retrieved correctly from localStorage.
•   Added console logs to verify the state changes in Pinia.
•   Disabled and re-enabled Vue Devtools extension.

Despite these efforts, the messages still don’t render on the screen, and the Vue Devtools error persists. Any help or insights would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

You should use a plugin for storing the state. https://www.npmjs.com/package/pinia-plugin-persistedstate. Would be easier to understand with the code of backend.js

This is a bug related to Vue devtools, not with your application. Should be safe to ignore.
https://chromewebstore.google.com/detail/vuejs-devtools/nhdogjmejiglipccpnnnanhbledajbpd?hl=en&pli=1
